# Safari 6 / Webinspector 2 - CSS Line Numbers and Stylesheet

Tags: css, safari, stylesheet, web-inspector

If I inspect CSS properties in the new Develeoper Console, for some reason there is no line number but a small arrow that you can hover or click to get the Line Number or Stylesheet. In the old Webinspector this was much faster, because the Stylesheet including linenumber was already written there as a link.

Does anybody know how to change this or a workaround? I already looked in the defaults but could not find anything.

I saw that there is already a bug ticket for this https://devforums.apple.com/message/705663, so hopefully it gets changed to the old behavior...

Comment: This thread over at [apple.stackexchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58691/how-to-revert-safari-6-web-inspector) that might interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out is that there is the option to use the webkit inspector in the [nightly builds](http://nightly.webkit.org) on Mountain Lion. You can choose it from the developer menu.

Answer (score 0):

try cmd+p and then type `:40`

the cursor will fo to line number 40